# What all must be included in a style guide?

Tags: style-guide

I am working on a project which is basically a document viewer, I have been asked to provide style guide for the same. I was wondering what all must be included in the style guide?

- should it include all the different elements that I Have used in the software?
- Do we need to specify the spacings(space between elements) also?

on what things should I emphasize while making a style guide?

Comment: Yes to your two points. In addition; colors, fonts and behaviour of elements on different screen sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on context. If this is a style guide (or guidelines for styling), see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide

This article is also very useful:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/designing-style-guidelines-for-brands-and-websites/

This is also a good resource: 
http://styleguides.io/

This is also a good useful guide: 
http://www.creativebloq.com/design/create-style-guides-1012963

Comment: http://styleguides.io/  is nice